# Dynamo IoC and Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm trying out Dynamo IoC with the web extensions for Mvc, and I see they've done a great work creating a custom HttpApplication to derive your Global.asax from. However it seems I'm missing something.

I want to accomplish DI in my controllers, but I'm stuck with the usual "The controller must have a parameterless constructor" problem.

This is what I do in my global.asax (which derives from `DynamoMvcAndWebApiApplication`):

```
protected override void RegisterDependencies(Dynamo.Ioc.IIocContainer container)
{
    container.Register<ILogger, FakeLogger>();
}
```

Then my controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        logger.Log("test");
        return View();
    }
}
```

This gets me the "no parameterless constructor error". I thought the web extensions of Dynamo already took care of whatever was required to make DI work.

If I add a parameterless constructor it gets called, but then my ILogger will be null, and I'll get a NullReferenceException in my action method.

I thought about having to implement a ControllerFactory but I also thought that if it was mandatory they would have provided it along with all other stuff for MVC, so I think that I am misusing what is provided.

I'd like to know if anyone knows how to make DI work in this scenario. Thanks.

Comment: I'm on my phone, or this would be a full answer, but look into the DependencyResolver class in System.Web.Mvc

Comment: Thank you for your interest, but the custom HttpApplication already takes care of setting the DependencyResolver with the custom one provided alongside the IoC container. My problem resides on having Controllers without parameterless constructor.

Comment: That's weird. None of the controllers in my current mvc project have default constructors and they're working just fine.

Comment: The absence of any explicit constructor is equivalent to the presence of the parameterless constructor in C#, so it's working as intended. You DO have the parameterless constructor at runtime. I don't, since I'm declaring a single constructor that does take a parameter. This makes the IL compiler NOT generate the parameterless constructor.

Comment: I tried the same approach with Ninject and its Mvc extensions and it works fine, out of the box. But I'd stick to dynamo because I've seen various benchmarks and all point to Dynamo as the one with better performance, and Ninject the slowest of them all.

Comment: If performance is an issue, take a look at [Simple Injector](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com). It is [faster than Dynamo](http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison) and works [out-of-the-box with MVC](http://nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector.MVC3) and allows many advanced features that Dynamo lacks.

Comment: I've heard that Griffin.Container is pretty fast and easy to get started with ;) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/440665/Having-fun-with-Griffin-Container (shameless self promotion)

Comment: @MatteoMosca I apologize for not being more clear. ALL of my controllers have an explicit, non-default constructor and are working with my DependencyResolver class that has been registered with MVC.

Comment: Also, I'll add another vote for Simple Injector. I've had a great experience using it.

Comment: Steven: To me that is a very bold claim when in fact my tests show that Dynamo.IoC is almost twice as fast as Simple Injector (latest from Nuget) when it comes to resolving transient instances.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a long digging and experimenting, it just seems that Dynamo doesn't fully integrate with MVC. I tried Ninject integration with MVC and it works fine, out of the box.

My guess is that Dynamo is just "not there yet", I'll keep checking on its updates in the future.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that it is because you don't register the HomeController when registering the dependencies.
According to your example you don't.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with MartinF. If you want your HomeController's dependencies to be resolved, you need to instantiate it by resolving it from your Dynamo container. Granted, I'm not seeing your resolve code, but I'm just guessing that's what's going on. I don't think it's a matter of "Dynamo doesn't fully integrate with MVC". Depending on how the container works, you may not even need to explicitly register HomeController with the container before trying to resolve it, but you DO need to ask the container to resolve it for you so that it may satisfy the dependencies. Just my guess based on the usage of other containers.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to disagree. Just check out how Ninject MVC integration is done. You install it and it works out of the box. I don't have to register manually every controller I add to the solution, ninject itegrates with MVC pipeline with its own controller factory and everything else needed to work.

Comment: Fair enough. However, you'll probably be better off with Autofac. It's much faster and feature-rich than Ninject. Just my two cents.